# Rule of thumb for log odds ratios effect size interpretation

Tags: r, regression, logistic, effect-size, odds-ratio

Let's start by fitting a logistic model:

```
fit <- lme4::glmer(vs ~ wt + (1|gear), data=mtcars, family="binomial")
summary(fit)
```

The output is the following:

```
Call:
glm(formula = vs ~ wt, family = "binomial", data = mtcars)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.9003  -0.7641  -0.1559   0.7223   1.5736  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)   5.7147     2.3014   2.483  0.01302 * 
wt           -1.9105     0.7279  -2.625  0.00867 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 43.860  on 31  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 31.367  on 30  degrees of freedom
AIC: 35.367

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

I understood that the values in the "Estimate" column are **log odds ratios**. I would like to interpret their size using rules of thumb, such as (in)famous Cohen's (1988) for standardized differences and such.

I found three sources of information:

- [This](http://imaging.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/statswiki/FAQ/effectSize) suggests using 1.5, 3.5 and 9 as cutoffs.
- [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_you_interpret_the_odds_ratio_OR) it is mentioned 1.5, 2.5 and 4.30.
- [Chen (2010)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610911003650383) suggests 1.68, 3.47 and 6.71.

As you can see, those seem to refer to "odds ratio" rather than to the "log odds ratio" returned by the logistic regression. No problem, I thought that I could transform these log odds into odds by running `exp(estimates)`.

And this is where I got stuck. For example, in the regression above, the "effect" of `wt` is negative, meaning that each increase of `wt` lowers the probability of the outcome. However, "simply" transforming this coefficient by `exp()` returns a very small, yet positive odds ratio (which is expected). It would mean that a negative effect could never have a large effect size, which is not right.

**My question is twofold:**

**1) How to "transform" these log odds to odds ratios so we can use the mentioned rules of thumb?**

**2) If not applicable, are there any rules of thumb for log odds ratios?**

DISCLAIMER: *I am aware of all the "we shouldn't use such rules of thumb", "they are dependent on the context", and mostly agree with it (yet need it anyway).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To transform log odds ratios to odds ratios, just (as you thought) use `exp()`.

If you want to use those rules of thumb for an odds ratio <1, just take the reciprocal to compare with the threshold (or use `exp()` on the absolute value of the log odds ratio).